# Windows 7 says "this copy is not genuine" build 7600

Tags: windows-7, windows-genuine-advantage

My Windows is complaining and says "Windows 7 build 7600 this copy of Windows is not genuine."

I was installing another copy on a virtual machine which must have triggered this.

I have a new license, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the "Computer" icon (if not on your Desktop, it should appear in your Start Menu), then choose "Properties" (or from within the Control Panel {icon view} choose "System").  The screen that appears should have an option near the bottom (you might have to scroll down to see it depending your screen's resolution) that reads "Change Product Key."

After you enter the new Product Key, you'll need to "activate" your license, at which point you'll find out if Microsoft considers it to be legitimate.

When you install a 1-user Windows license on two machines, this type of error message will appear.  It's good that you have a second license that you can use (as long as it's not being used anywhere else).